# Problems on importing tinyec module

Tags: python, module

I have installed tinyec. But when i import it, it says that there is no such module.
If I use *whereis tinyec* it shows nothing.
//whereis tinyec
//tinyec:

How can i use tinyec?
Someone help.
Thanks.

Comment: Please provide other additional information as well including OS, python version, how did you install, where was it installed etc.

Comment: I have installed python 2.7 in ubuntu virtual machine. I used the cmd  sudo pip install tinyec